# Connecting to multiple Oracle databases hosted on different machines - Username as common and different password for each database

Tags: bash, oracle

Environment:

We have ~100 databases hosted on multiple machines. All databases have common username but password is different on every database.

Issue:

How can I read the password and TNS (Service name) from an external file one by one and connect to the each database and run the sql query and pass the output to a logfile.

What is done so far:

1. Created `pass` file that contains password and Service_Name and delimiter ":"

```
cat pass
Loufr#123:PROD
Brinj#6523:TEST
```

2. Another file `dblist` is created with all the `dbnames` (that matches the service names) in step 1

```
cat dblist
PROD
TEST
DEV
QA
Quality
```

---

Goal:

read name of the database from `dblist` and find the password from `pass` file for that database.

Use `dbname` and `password` to connect to database in following string

```
sqlplus -s dbsnmp@${TNS}/${Password}
spool output.log
@query.sql
exit
```

Comment: Can you add an example of some lines of such external file? Not with the real data of course;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should do the trick:

```
while read TNS; do
    Password="$(sed -n "s/\(.*\):${TNS}$/\1/p" pass)"
    [ "$Password" ] && sqlplus -s dbsnmp@${TNS}/${Password} << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off 
set heading off

spool output.log
@query.sql

exit;
EOF
done < dblist
```

If you just ask for a script parsing the files containing the credentials.
You can see also: [Connect to sqlplus in a shell script and run SQL scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277983/connect-to-sqlplus-in-a-shell-script-and-run-sql-scripts)

Comment: I have elaborated the question. Added contents of the file. Can you have a look please.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta I updated the script.

Comment: Thank you very much Davide. It worked. I also want to learn this kinda scripting, if you can guide me from where to start.

Comment: I read long times ago the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), but you can find lots of more updated resources. Same for sed, here's my [bible](https://sites.google.com/site/davidemadrisan2/sed1line52.txt).

Comment: @DavideMadrisan, it is **user/password@tns** , not **user@tns/password**. Besides, with your solution I would be able to run a `ps` in the terminal and read the passwords. It is better to encapsulate the connection inside  `sqlplus` by using the `nolog` option and then using the `connect` command.

Comment: Connection to database works in both ways user/password@tns , or user@tns/password...sir

Comment: And I agree with you to use the connect command to connect so that passwords are not readable with ps. Thank you for the suggestion. I will make a change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get what you want but ‘solutions’ that store plaintext passwords or that show them on the command line are wrong.
There is a solution for storing passwords since many versions, called oracle wallet. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBIMI/walet.htm#DBIMI10236
Using this makes scripting a lot easier because you can limit your logon code to something like: “sqlplus /@tns” this will dig up the credentials in the wallet using tns as the key and make a connection with it, without even showing the username.

There are many security problems in the world. Why not use the tools to make applications a bit more secure?